# Reading an sql file in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to populate a database table by reading some sql from a file.sql and putting it into a string before calling the query. But I seem to be unable to load the file into a string. What gives?

```
function db_data() {
    WP_Filesystem();
    global $wp_filesystem;
    global $wpdb;


    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "tableName";
    $file = "/sql/my_insert_query.sql";
    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO $table_name (id, something) ";
    $sql_insert .= $wp_filesystem->get_contents( $file );
    $rows_affected = $wpdb->query( $sql_insert );
}
```

The $sql_insert turns out as an empty string. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

Found the way to get to the right directory path. This is the finished code:

```
function db_data() {
    WP_Filesystem();
    global $wp_filesystem;
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "tableName";
    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO $table_name (id, something) ";
    $dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
    $file =  $dir."/sql/my_insert_query.sql";
    $sql_values = $wp_filesystem->get_contents( $file );
    $sql_insert .= $sql_values;
    $rows_affected = $wpdb->query( $sql_insert );
}
```

For the answer on finding and reading the sql file. Check the answer below.

Comment: is ```/sql/my_insert_query.sql``` the absolute path? Because if it's relative to your document root then it will come out empty.

Comment: @amenadiel It's not the absolute path. I used WP_PLUGIN_DIR but it came out without slashes so that didn't help either. So I should use the absolute path but how do I get to it? Because WP_PLUGIN_DIR gives me the path with the slashes missing.

Comment: how about ```$file = "./sql/my_insert_query.sql";``` that should be relative to your wordpress root.

Comment: @amenadiel I tried it now but it still returns an empty string.

Comment: @amenadiel Thank you. I'm at work now and I need to go so I might not reply until Monday.. But I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first start debugging the file path issue. There are two things you can use here.

```
function db_data() {
    WP_Filesystem();
    global $wp_filesystem;
    global $wpdb;
    echo 'Current Path is '. __DIR__;
    $file =  __DIR__."/sql/my_insert_query.sql";
    if(!is_readable($file)) {
        echo 'File not found or not readable '.$file;
    }     
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "tableName";

    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO $table_name (id, something) ";
    $sql_insert .= $wp_filesystem->get_contents( $file );
    $rows_affected = $wpdb->query( $sql_insert );
}
```

That will at least provide more insight about the filepath.

Comment: I cannot use echo to see what's going on because it doesn't show up when I activate the plugin in WordPress but I used an insert query to see what happens in my database and I was able to find the right directory. And now my sql file reading and inserting works! 

Only problem is, __DIR__ didn't work and WP_PLUGIN_DIR gives me the path without slashes.. I can't hardcode the path so how do I do it?

Comment: WP_PLUGIN_DIR should give you the path without trailing slash, same as __DIR__. If the latter didn't work, maybe you're using PHP 5.2. You can also replace it with ```dirname(__FILE__);``` but WP_PLUGIN_DIR is OK too.